# SublimeText 3 no me salen las etiquetas HTML5 al tabular

Tags: sublimetext, emmet

como hago para que me aparezca la estructura de html5 en sublime text ya que escribo html y sale el cuerpo peo si escribo html5 o html:5 no me aparece la versión 5 ... creo que es un "emmet" como hago para que me funcione ?

```
con lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=escon lang=es
```

Comment: creo que deberias apretar en view, syntax y luego HTLM..

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que instalar Emmet,

Ve a preferencias > Package Control > Install Package > emmet.

Comment: hago esos pasos pero  escribo emmet y no aparece nada

Comment: Respondeme la siguiente pregunta, ya tienes instalado el package control?

Comment: creo q si revise y dice : plugins loaded
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2019-02-09 12:34:45, next run at 2019-02-09 13:34:45 or after

Comment: porque al ingresar el cod me sale un error print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
286331

Comment: Has lo siguiente: ctrl+` una vez te aparesca la consola ingresas el siguiente codigo >

Comment: import urllib.request,os,hashlib; h = '6f4c264a24d933ce70df5dedcf1dcaee' + 'ebe013ee18cced0ef93d5f746d80ef60'; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)

Comment: Como te dice Alex,  en el Menu Preferences->Package Control [digitar Install Package]  y luego aparece otro recuadro en el que tenes que digitar [emment]

Comment: https://emmet.io/blog/sublime-text-3/

Answer (score 0):

Pues creo que no has instalado el emmet o no creo que lo estas haciendo bien

escribe: html

o tal vez reinicie su sublime

Comment: Las respuestas son para cuando sabes cual es el problema y la solución. En caso contrario, puedes dejar un comentario.